# Не работает richtextbox когда изменяю ее через ссылку класса

Tags: c#, winforms

Вот мой  код:

```
MainForm form = new MainForm();
form.richTextBox1.Text += "пример" + Environment.NewLine;
```

Когда добавляю текст через это, то ничего не получается, ошибок нет (`richTextBox1` и так `public`),
а когда добавляю текст через это:

```
richTextBox1.Text += "пример" + Environment.NewLine;
```

без каких либо ссылок, то все получается. В чем проблема? Я хочу логировать работу программы в `richTextBox1`, для этого мне нужно вызывать метод или же напрямую изменять - ни одно не работает.

Answer (score 3):

```
MainForm form = new MainForm();
form.richTextBox1.Text += "пример" + Environment.NewLine;
```

Здесь Вы создаете (но не показываете на экране) новую форму, куда добавляете текст. Когда метод с этими двумя строчками отработает, локальную переменную `form` благополучно уберет сборщик мусора.

---

```
richTextBox1.Text += "пример" + Environment.NewLine;
```

Здесь Вы находитесь внутри `MainForm`, которая уже видна на экране.

Comment: А зачем мне открывать вторую форму, мне нужно чтобы менялся ричбокс именно уже на открытой форме

Comment: @ChaYKa `MainForm form = new MainForm();` - это новая форма, а не "уже открытая". Зачем Вы ее создаете?

Comment: аа, понятно) А как сделать тогда сделать чтобы менялась именно уже открытая форма?

Comment: @ChaYKa Передавать туда, где Вам надо добавить текст в `richTextBox1`, ссылку на эту существующую форму.

Comment: я не очень понимаю как это сделать( Работаю первый день с формами, чтобы мне передать текст в richtextbox мне нужно именно создавать новую форму чтобы добавить текст, а иначе ошибка про нестатические поля.. Не можете подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: @ChaYKa Не могу, потому что Вы не сказали, где находится код `MainForm form = new MainForm();`.

Comment: Этот код находитя в Program.cs